# Locus of tangency points of tangents issued from a fixed point to a certain set of circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let us fix a point $A$ on a fixed line segment $P B$.  What is the set of points $X$ that can be obtained by taking a circle $o $ passing through $A$ and $B$,drawing a line through $P$ tangent to $o$ and calling this tangency point $X$?

Comment: How many nicknames and accounts do you have?

Comment: I don't agree to close a question which has its own interest. But we can ask the OP what he has done on this problem.

Comment: I have somewhat modified my answer, and added in particular a reference.

Comment: @JeanMarie The answer is related to inversion. It's the circle centered at $P$ that maps $A$ to $B$. For me it is straight forward. You draw one arbitrary circle through $A$ and $B$ and then you construct the orthogonal to it centered at $P$. And that's it. Meanwhile, I have seen people shutting down problems far more non-trivial and fun. And often,  judging by their track record, some of these people did not even have contribution to the geometry tag.

Comment: @Futurologist You are right. As you, I like very much using inversion (see for example my answer in (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1676882)). The only problem is that if the OP is probably young, and it will be rather difficult for her/him to enter into the subject following this path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k=\sqrt{PA.PB}$.

> Result: The answer is the circle with center $P$ and radius $k$ (see figure).

Let us call "pencil$_{AB}$" the set of circles passing through $A$ and $B$.

The short demonstration of the result above relies on the concept of power $Pow(P,(C))$ of a point $P$ wrt to a circle $(C)$. If you don't know it, and as we are in the case of a point which is outside all circles of "pencil$_{AB}$", have a look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point), where it is shown that there are two ays to compute the power:

$$Pow(P,(C))=PA.PB=PX^2.$$

Thus, whatever the circle of "pencil$_{AB}$", the power of $M$ will remain the same, because the product $PA.PB$ is a constant.

[image]